# Will these two random variables be independent?

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Assume you have two continuous random varaibles $X,Y$. Also assume that their joint probability density function can be written

$f(x,y)=p_1(x)p_2(y)$,

must they then be independent?

The problem is that we don't know if $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the marginal distributions as well. It seems natural that they should be independent. But I do not see how to prove this. Is there a simple way to prove this, or is there a counter-example?

Comment: If the joint density separates multiplicatively, then there are proportional forms of abs(p1) and abs(p2) that must be densities (that is, they integrate to one).  Those densities must be the marginals, as is easily shown by direct evaluation of the marginals from the multiplicative form of the joint density.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of two *events* being independent is that
$$
P(A\cap B) = P(A) P(B)
$$
The definition of two *random variates* $X$ and $Y$ being independent is that for all $x, y$ the the events $(X\leq x)$ and  $(Y\leq y)$ are independent events.  It is pretty easy, then, to use the above definition of independent events to show that this implies that the cumulative distributions satisfy 
$$
F_{X,Y}(x,y)= F_X(x)\,F_Y(y)
$$
Also, given that $F_{X,Y}(x,y)= F_X(x)\,F_Y(y)$, it is easy to see that the event-specified definition of independence is met.  So let's call this the CDF independence criterion -- it is equivalent to the by-definition independence criterion.

In turn, assuming only that the probability *densities* $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ and the joint probability density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ all exist, it is straightforward to see that 
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)= f_X(x)\,f_Y(y)
$$

The zinger, of course, is that there are some cumulative distribution functions which don't have corresponding pdfs, but we can ignore that annoyance because we are given that
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)= p_1(x)p_2(y) = f_X(x)\,f_Y(y)
$$

Now if $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(y)$ are both integrable, you can integrate to obtain the CDF independence criterion, showing that if $f_{X,Y}(x,y)= p_1(x)p_2(y)$ for all $x,y$ then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

But we know that $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(y)$ are both integrable, because by definition a density is a non-negative Lebesgue-integrable function.

In an arbitrary measurable space, this property still holds, since again by definition a densityis a measurable function.